# SMTP connect() failed. No puedo enviar correos desde la página

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpmailer, smtp

Trato de enviar un email a traves de PHPMailer, pero no hay manera de conseguirlo, tengo este código que deberia ir, y no funciona.

Ingreso todos los parámetros del servidor que es el de smtp.gmail.com, usuario, contraseña pero no me permite el envío de correos.

Ya probe de quitar del mail la validación en 2 pasos, pero tampoco funciono. No le encuentro la vuelta.

editado :
Este es el mensaje de error
debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c26-20020a056214071a00b0067f3763eb54sm2523414qvz.88 - gsmtp debug level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO cliente.com debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2607:f298:5:102b::b7e:b594] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH PLAIN debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 debug level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c26-20020a056214071a00b0067f3763eb54sm2523414qvz.88 - gsmtp debug level 1; message: SMTP ERROR: User & Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c26-20020a056214071a00b0067f3763eb54sm2523414qvz.88 - gsmtp debug level 2; message: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.debug level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection c26-20020a056214071a00b0067f3763eb54sm2523414qvz.88 - gsmtp debug level 2; message: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingError al enviar el correo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Validación del formulario
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : "";
    $contacto = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

    // Enviar correo con PHPMailer
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // Agrega 'true' para habilitar excepciones
    // Configuro el servidor SMTP y las credenciales
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // Cambiado a 'ssl'
    $mail->AuthType = 'PLAIN';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;  // Cambiado a 465 para SSL
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Username = 'mailorigen@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'pass';

    // Configura el correo

    $mail->setFrom('mailorigen@gmail.com', $contacto);
    $mail->AddAddress('maildestino@gmail.com');
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    // $mail->Mailer = "smtp";


    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Asunto';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    // Enviar correo
    try {
        if ($mail->send()) {
            header('location: mensaje.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Error al enviar el correo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            // header('location: mensaje_error.php');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error al enviar el correo: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    header('location: mensaje_error.php');
}
```

Comment: Hola. Pon temporalmente el modo debug en forma *hablador*  agregando esta línea: `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`, prueba de nuevo y revisa el mensaje de error. Debería describirte con exactitud cuál es el problema. Si no logras entender lo que dice el mensaje agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit], y enmascarando toda información personal y/o sensible como rutas de archivos en tu servidor, direcciones de correo, etc.

Comment: Ya esta editado!

Comment: *`Username and Password not accepted`* ¿Seguro de que estás usando el nombre de usuario y password correctos para conectarte a esa cuenta de correo electrónico?

Comment: Si me di cuenta de eso, pero si estoy usando los correctos. No entiendo porque me da el error

Comment: Google ha agregado nuevas capas de seguridad, conviene que revises [este enlace](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps). Según como tengas configurado el acceso a tu cuenta de Google deberás dar permiso en forma de aplicación, usar tokens, etc.

Comment: Okey entiendo. probe con una cuenta de outlook y me queda cargando la página sin ejecutar ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Ya, supongo que ocurrirá algo parecido. Hoy día las compañías serias usan niveles de seguridad altos, por todos los riesgos que implicaría una autentificación plana. Entiendo que es engorroso al principio, pero si intentas escribir algo serio deberás esforzarte un poquito y entender cómo funcionan esas autentificaciones e implementarlas en tus programas.

Comment: [Revisa aquí](https://github.com/decomplexity/SendOauth2) para más detalles.

Comment: O, si vas a trabajar con Gmail, puedes usar la propia API de Google, en vez de usar PHPMailer. [Esta es la página del repositorio de la biblioteca cliente de Google](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). Lo más engorroso es la configuración inicial, pero puedes instalar los archivos con Composer. Luego sólo creas un proyecto en Google Cloud Console y decides el modo de autenticación. A la larga esto es más simple y te abre al camino a usar en el futuro otras herramientas de Google como Formularios, Sheets, Docs, etc.